# How to download a directory over FTP?

Tags: downloads, ftp

I want to download a directory over FTP. The directory is very large, and it would be useful if I can pause and resume the download as needed.

The target FTP directory is static. That is, it's contents won't change in time. And no authentication is needed.

What's the best tool to do this job?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/how-do-you-recursively-ftp-a-folder-in-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wget` should work:

```
wget -r -l 0 ftp://username:password@some.host/some_dir/*
```

`wget` is tool for downloading files.

- `-r` means recursive.
- `-l 0` for  infinite recursion, because `-r` by default have recursion depth of 5.
- `some_dir/` is relative to user home dir. If you want absolute path add one more `/` after host name.

Maybe you have to use `--user` and `--password` arguments to get it to work on Ubuntu.(according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113886/how-do-you-recursively-ftp-a-folder-in-linux)

Comment: And how to pause/resume download?

Comment: Stop it, and then start it again for resuming. It will start where it was stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with curl :

```
curl -u user:password 'ftp://site/folder/file.txt' -o /tmp/file.txt
```

or with gui [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)

Comment: I want to download an entire directory (along with its contents, recursively), not a single file.

Answer (score 0):

I would use lftp and mirror function in it. You can download files in pararell, stop, resume, limit speed etc.

Alternativly - you can use wget

```
wget -m -c ftp://serwer/directory
```

If you wish to stop - simply stop wget. For resume - do it again - it will not download files which was already downloaded.

If you wish to download/reject specific files you can use -A or -R option (or - if you wish to specify it via regexp - --accept-regex/--reject-regex)

Comment: `wget` downloads a lot of garbage files (index.html, and other useless stuff). How can I prevent that?

Comment: hm? wget in ftp should download only this, what is in directory. If there is no index.html file - it shouldn't download nothing like it. Maybe are you download via http protocol? When are you using -m option - only one created file is .listing used for caching list of files in directory.

If you wish to download/reject specific files you can use -A or -R option (or - if you wish to specify it via regexp - --accept-regex/--reject-regex).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK ftp doesn't support downloading the directory directly.

You can use [`FileZilla`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/filezilla/) for this purpose. It stores all your transfer in queue. You can resume the transfer later once it is paused or  when you reconnect to server.

Answer (score 0):

I tried those commands but wget interpreted user:pass has being the server and port so i ran this command and it worked, hope it help :

```bash
wget -m -c 'ftp://servidor/directory/' --ftp-user=<your ftp username> --ftp-password=<your ftp password>
```